# Keeping session alive for given time in two applications

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have 2 applications and I have hosted second one as a sub-application of first application.
Both applications are using common application pool.Both are having their separate sessions.

URLs of applications looks like: 
1. mysite.com 
2. mysite.com/store

My requirement is, if session in one application is active then session in other application should remain active.
Can you please tell me how to implement this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you elaborate more about **integrated applications**? Do you mean one site is hosted inside another site's folder? What are their URLs look like?

Comment: I have 2 separate applications and I have hosted second one as a virtual directory of first application.
URLs: mysite.com and mysite.com/store

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keeping a related ASP.NET application's session alive from another ASP.NET application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642682/keeping-a-related-asp-net-applications-session-alive-from-another-asp-net-appli)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sharing sessions across applications using the ASP.NET Session State Service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868316/sharing-sessions-across-applications-using-the-asp-net-session-state-service) and [Share Session between two web sites using asp.net and state server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438912/share-session-between-two-web-sites-using-asp-net-and-state-server)